# Can't use Nexus to debug

Tags: android, shell, android-emulator, adb, nexus-7

I have as strange error - after a lot of fiddling about with drivers, I was able to set up my nexus 5 and nexus 7 with my computer so that adb recognises them. I can even shell in to the devices and do as I please.

However, I want to use them to debug an application (i.e. test my app on them). However, they don't show up on the AVD manager and so I can't select them to use.

I've tried both devices, and put them in PTP (Camera option) - no luck. I've also enabled USB debugging, and still no luck.

Does anyone have any idea why they'd show under adb.exe (command line) and I'd be able to shell in, but I can't use them as an emulator?

Thanks,
FYP

Comment: Download Google USB drivers under Extras in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: "However, they don't show up on the AVD manager" they shouldn't. They should appear in the "run" window.

Comment: @DoctororDrive I could have sworn that in Eclipse (currently using IntelliJ but used Eclipse last time) they appeared in AVD? Either way, I'll check this when I'm home. Thanks.

Comment: @ChuongPham Already done - although I did have problems and had to do something else. I also do occassionally get usb not recognised which is annoying, but alas, Google!

Comment: @fypfyp: Also, ensure you have Android SDK and ADT to have the exact same version. For example, if you use SDK v22.6.1, then you must also use ADT v22.6.1. This will prevent a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1):

What IDE are you using?  As far as I know, AVD Manager wont display your connected device in the AVD Manager itself because only Android Emulator will be displayed on it.

However, since you can access the device using adb, if you have the APK of the application that you are trying to debug, you can try installing it using

```
adb install yourapk.apk
```

Comment: I'm currently playing with Intellij and it doesn't show up - However, last year I used Eclipse for a project and I used to be able to compile and run in Eclipse, and it would automatically choose my android device without me having to use cmd.